# Associating unique logging-calls to an id across runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I need to be able to associate a log to an id that stays persistent across runs e.g:

```py
logging.log("Hello") # 1
logging.log("World") # 2
```

Obviously this only works as long as you don't modify the code

```py
logging.log("Hello") # 1
logging.log("beautiful") # 2
logging.log("World") # 3 <--- ID should be 2 here!!
```

The solution would seem simple... just create a hash over the log message and you're good to go right?
Sadly, I have to consider following possibility:

```py
logging.log("Hello")
logging.log("World")
...
logging.log("World") # This would assign to the same hash/id as the previous log to 'World'
```

The only ideas i've come up with to tackle this problem are:

1. Running static analysis or a diff on the code beforehand and analyzing it

   - Are there any tools suitable for the job?
   - Can they be implemented realistically?
2. Making the user manage the IDs (not very user friendly)

```py
logging.log("10", "Hello")
logging.log("20", "World")
```

Or is there another solution I'm not seeing?

Comment: Can you give a better definition of when the id should not change? If the code is refactored at what point should it get a different id?

Comment: The id shouldn't change when the a specific log of e.g.: "World" is already known to the system (through a previous run). The purpose is that this id is fixed across runs, yet a second log of "World" would result in a new id.
I'm not concerned about someone switching up the order of the 2nd log of "World" with the first. i.e: I just want to make sure a second log (during the same run) gets a seperate id.
Writing it out like that made the problem seem a lot less complex in my mind.
(1/2)

Comment: I might be able to get away with creating a FIFO-queue with all existing ids of "World", popping the id's as they get used, and creating a new id when my queue is empty.
(2/2)